# MediaWiki in multi-server environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, mediawiki

I'd like to ask about some strategies with MediaWiki. How would you run MediaWiki with good performance on a multi-server environment? Since it has configuration files it will also need some sort of central configuration.

Resources available are all of AWS' services.

Does anybody have experience and ideas?

Here are the main issues I fear will occur:

- There is no way to save images between multiple server at high speeds
- Caching to a central server will be very slow
- I don't know exactly how to configure proper cache - or Squid cache (no tutorials...)
- The site can't properly, automatically auto-scale
- Configuration changes require completely new machine images so they autoscale

Comment: You might want to take a look at the infrastructure running the largest MediaWiki site, wikipedia,  described in [the presentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Presentations) by Faidon Liambotis

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather generic, so I can only provide a rather generic answer. In particular, you mention a multi-server environment, but it's not clear to me whether you want a multi-site installation.

In general: consider first of all what you actually need. Most MediaWiki sites don't need squid, simpler caching will do. Same for uploads. Running your site on a single server eliminates most of your worries, consider the option. If one server is not enough, you most likely need a separate database box as first thing. See [[Manual:Performance tuning]].

For some use cases, one of the [premade images](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/ref=dtl_navgno_search_box?page=1&searchTerms=mediawiki) might do. For uploads, there is an [AWS extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AWS). If you really need multiple application servers, you'll probably need puppet, salt or similar to sync them.

If instead you want a multi-site installation, this is usually called a [wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family). Again, a wiki family might still run on a single server, or on a single database server (sharing the users table, for instance). There are some "wiki farms" running on AWS, refer to the manual for links.